# Fusion tables query does not fetch some

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm having an issue on this table: [1g_ydg74ooUSBzNfQBHOIdgrOKhxZD_92In8xTDg](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1g_ydg74ooUSBzNfQBHOIdgrOKhxZD_92In8xTDg)

I'm trying to fetch some results by CODE_DEPT. I used the filter

```
CODE_DEPT IN ('001', '002', '003', '02A', '02B')
```

and only the 3 first are fetched.

Any idea what's going on ? 
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like CODE_DEPT is identified as a numeric column. The last two codes are not numeric and so would not match anything. If you change the column to type Text and you should be OK.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I have to create a copy of the table.